# Ubuntu 19.04 screen orientation issue

Tags: system-installation, graphics, amd-graphics

I have hp probook 4431s with an AMD card and when I boot into 19.04 live cd the screen was inverted (never happened on the previous 18.10). I installed it upside down but when I booted into the OS the screen was in normal state but the functionality is still upside down and the cursor was upside down and I don't know the solution. I also tried xrandr but didn't get it right. I have not so much of deep knowledge and really don't want to switch back to Windows.

Comment: 19.04 seems to have an issue with interpreting the orientation sensor backwards; my HP Pavilion dv7 has the upside down screen as well after upgrading. I was able to get the desktop back into the correct orientation with `xrandr -o normal` and then turning on orientation lock. Unfortunately, this only applies to my desktop when logged in, and the lock screen is still upside down when I'm not logged in. I think you would have to entirely disable whatever triggers the auto rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

Remove the above sensor

Comment: This does prevent the screen from flipping upside down, but essentially removes all functionality of those sensors. Is there a way to configure it properly?